# Get tag image which contain file name using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get images with a certain file name using regex:

I am trying this:

```
/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"].+('myfilename.jpg').+[^\'"])[\'"].+\/>/
```

Problem is that it brings back the image and everything after it till another `/>`.

I get back:

```
<img alt="IMG_2329-1024x668" class="alignnone wp-image-10624" height="396" src="/sites/default/files/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/IMG_2329-1024x668-1024x668.jpg" width="607" /> asdl;f jadsflja ds;fjadsf ;aklsdfj ads;flkjadsf;aldjsfadsf <br/>
```

Instead of:

```
<img alt="IMG_2329-1024x668" class="alignnone wp-image-10624" height="396" src="/sites/default/files/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/IMG_2329-1024x668-1024x668.jpg" width="607" />
```

Comment: use `?` https://regex101.com/ is a great way to test your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `.+` is greedy, it will get the longest match, while you want it to stop at the first match.

Maybe try adding some `?` to make it non-greedy (note: regex dialect dependent)

```
/<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"].+?('myfilename.jpg').+?[^\'"])[\'"].+?\/>/
```